# Arduino serial connection requires init?

Tags: bluetooth, arduino

My `arduino Uno` , is connected to a bluetooth module(hm-10) , and they connect via uart from the `arduino` `tx,rx` pins .

Something strange happens:

1. The arduino  is starting a serial Communication with the module right when they get power.
2. then some other device is connecting to the module(wirelessly they paired)
3. here, the Arduino connection with the module somehow lost, and in order to get the data from the module's UART to Arduino ,i have to **RESET** the arduino here,let it reconnect with the module(i guess) and only then i can send data to the module, and the arduino will see this data.

If i *dont* reset the arduino AFTER the module is paired with the remote device, the arduino will not get data from the module :

```
 void setup() 
 {

   pinMode(13, OUTPUT);

   Serial.begin(9600); 
   while (!Serial) 
   {
    ;  
   }

 }

  String content = "";
  char character;  


 void loop() 
{

      while(Serial.available()) 
      {

      character = Serial.read();
      content.concat(character);
          digitalWrite(13, HIGH);  
       }

    if(content=="myName")
       digitalWrite(13, HIGH);    
       else
         digitalWrite(13,LOW);  

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to try:

1. Can you remove the fail to initialize loop?

   while (!Serial) 
      {
       ;
      }
2. If that doesn't work, try adding a delay before your Arduino's serial initialization.

`Delay(1000);
Serial.begin(9600);`

I've a theory your hardware is causing some garbage data on power-on, which is preventing the Arduino's UART from initializing.